# iOS In-App Purchases invalid product identifier in ONLY iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to test In App Purchase within the sandbox environment.
And I've checked all http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/ methioned.
It's my code of getting products response from APPLE SERVER.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"############ REQUEST RECEIVED RESPONSE %@", response.products);

    for (NSString *productID in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product identifier: %@", productID);
    }
}
```

I can get all my products with iOS5.X devices. But all invalidProductIdentifiers with iOS6.x devices. I'm very confused. I have no idea about what can cause this. 
It's my test results below.

I've tested in all versions of simulator, FINE

*Device              *iOSVersion                           Result

---

ipod3                 5.0                             FINE

---

iphone4              5.1.1                            FINE

---

ipod5                 6.1.2                    Invalid Product Identifiers

---

iphone5              6.1.3                     Invalid Product Identifiers

---

anyone has some ideas?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail. Show what you have researched so far.

Comment: thank u for reply.  I did everything I can such as confirm bundle_id, product_id in itunesconnect, make sure all devices are not jailbreak. I can get correct response in iOS5.X devices. Is there any changes in IOS6??

Comment: It's another question by saying "Please take a wild guess" while I'm too busy to give details.

Comment: added some more details, any help?

Answer (score 4):

iOS 6 Simulator does not support testing In-App Purchase.
Please use a device to test your apps that use this feature.

Please Check This Link :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/